# QObject connect QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile to QVariant

Tags: c++, qt, profile, qml, signals-slots

I have a QML part of my application that needs to know what state I'm in. The `currentProfileChanged` function has a signal giving me a `QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile` that I want to convert to a `QVaraint` so that the QML can understand the profile as a number between 0 and 7, but this function:

```
QObject::connect(deviceInfo, 
    SIGNAL(currentProfileChanged(QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile)),
    rootObject,
    SLOT(changePower(QVariant(QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile))));
```

Gives this strange error:

```
[Qt Message] Object::connect: No such slot
     QDeclarativeItem_QML_3::changePower(QVariant(QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile))  
     in C:/Users/Gerhard/QTProjects/Raker/main.cpp:142
```

What I am doing wrong here?

If I try this:

```
QObject::connect(deviceInfo, 
    SIGNAL(currentProfileChanged(QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile)),
    rootObject,
    SLOT(changePower(QVariant(QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile))));
```

It says this:

```
[Qt Message] Object::connect: No such slot
     QDeclarativeItem_QML_3::changePower(QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile)  
     in C:/Users/Gerhard/QTProjects/Raker/main.cpp:142
```

If I change any or both to just QVariant it also complains about incompatible arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there appears to be no easier way I had to write a function to convert the types and add some more signal slots but at least it works now, here's my function if you want it:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QSystemDeviceInfo>
#include <QDebug>

using namespace QtMobility;


class changeVAriant : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void toVariant(QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile prof)
    {
        emit newVariant(QVariant(prof));
    }
signals:
    void newVariant(QVariant);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The slot function cannot have a parameter that doesn't match a parameter in the signal. Your slot should be specified as `..SLOT(changePower(QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile))..`

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that but it hen complains: [Qt Message] Object::connect: No such slot QDeclarativeItem_QML_3::changePower(QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile) in C:/Users/Gerhard/QTProjects/Raker/main.cpp:142

Comment: Than change your slot declaration from `changePower(QVariant(QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile))` to `changePower(QSystemDeviceInfo::Profile)` as Arnold Spence suggested

Comment: it Doesn't have a declaration in qml it just looks like this: function changePower(power). All the other that look like this take a QVAriant and then they work.

Comment: I haven't used QML so I'm afraid I can't suggest anything more. Hopefully somebody that has can help you out. Sorry.